# Can I record a TV screen with a Linux computer?

Tags: capture, video-capture-card, video-recording

If I ever decide to get into uploading videos to websites on a game console I'd like to have a Linux that supports TV recording.

So basically I'm wondering if something such as a capture card works with Debian based Linux distros.

Comment: Ok. Are you looking for a capture card or are you looking to record what's on screen???

Comment: Do you mean record TV programs or record a PS/Xbox game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a Linux supported capture card or device.  While there are many capture devices on the market, it might be hit or miss to find one that will work in Linux out of the box.

There a **[HDHomerun](https://www.silicondust.com/)** capture device that has [Ubuntu Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HDHomeRun) in the repository.

You can use the GUI or a [Command Line Interface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adJYHW030Gs) to capture video from the TV.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm thinking about recording speedruns of Ps2 games! Thanks again.